# lftp mirroring directories that don't meet my criteria

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mirror, lftp

I've been writing an lftp script that should mirror a remote directory to a local directory efficiently, possibly transferring multiple gigabyte files at a time.

One of the requirements is that a local user can delete the local file when it is no longer needed, and since I will have multiple "local" computers running this script, I don't want to delete the remote file until I know everyone who needs it, has it. So the script uses the --newer-than flag to only mirror files that are new/modified on the remote server since the last time the lftp script ran locally.

Here's the important bits of the script:

```
lftp -u $login,$pass $host << EOF
set ftp:ssl-allow yes
set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes
set ftp:ssl-protect-list yes
set ftp:ssl-force yes
set mirror:use-pget-n 5

mirror -X * -I share*/* --newer-than=/local/file/last.run --continue --parallel=5 $remote_dir $local_dir

quit
EOF
```

Note that the EOF isn't the actual end of the bash script.

So I EXCLUDE everything in $remote_dir except anything in the share/ directory, including the share/ directory itself that are NEWER than the last.run file's timestamp.

This works as expected except in one case where say I have another specifically named directory in share/ called shareWHATEVER/

So share/shareWHATEVER/stuff.txt exists.

The first time it runs, shareWHATEVER/stuff.txt are copied remotely to locally, and all is well.

If I delete the shareWHATEVER directory locally in its entirety, including stuff.txt, then the next time the script runs, stuff.txt it NOT mirrored, but shareWHATEVER is, even though the timestamps have not changed on the remote server.

So locally it looks like share/shareWHATEVER/ where the directory is empty.

Any idea why shareWHATEVER is being copied over even though neither its own timestamp or any of its files' timestamps are --newer-than my local check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, creating directories even when no files are copied is just the way `lftp` works (and the `mirror` option `--no-empty-dirs` doesn't change this behaviour).

You could discuss this in the [lftp mailing list](http://lftp.yar.ru/list.html).